# Nuxt3 with ioredis Docker Configuration

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, nuxt.js

I've Nuxt3 project, in which I'm using io-redis and Nitro storage options to save data in Cache (io-redis)

in nuxt.config.js file

```
    storage: {
      redis: {
        driver: "redis",
        url: "redis://localhost:6379",
        /* redis connector options */
        // port: 6379, // Redis port
        // host: "", // Redis host
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        lazyConnect: true,
        keepAlive: 1000,
      },
    },
  }
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: the_tezos_redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  nuxt-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Docker file

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:18-alpine

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install Nuxt.js and ioredis dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose the port that the Nuxt.js app will run on
EXPOSE 3000
```

My app is running but facing this redis connectivity issue.

Also, this url is not accessible http://localhost:6379/

Redis is running but connection gets rejected.

How i can fix this issue.

Comment: I can't find command to run nuxt app in your dockerfile.
for example: CMD ["npm", "start"]